# How do I attach jquery ui elements with access to html attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I apologize for the wording of the question but half my problem is not knowing how to ask this question.

### Scenario

I've created a php form item called date. It's just a textfield with some special classes and attributes. HTML output looks like this:

```
<div class="form-item type-date name-dob required">
    <label for="dob"> DOB <span class="required-text">*</span></label>
    <input type="textfield" name="dob" maxlength="10" size="12" value="07/01/2015" class="datepicker processed hasDatepicker" change_month="1" change_year="1" min_year="-120" max_year="+0" id="dp1452013829790">
</div>
```

I then want to use these custom attributes, change_month, change_year, etc. To attach the datepicker from one js call instead of writing the js for each instance of a date field.

```
$('.form-item.type-date input').datepicker(
{
  'changeMonth' : $(this).attr('change_month') == "1",
  'changeYear' : $(this).attr('change_year') == "1",
  'yearRange' : $(this).attr('min_year') + ':' + $(this).attr('max_year')
});
```

### Problem

The portion of the js code `$(this)` is not defined. I expected it to be an instance of the selector `$('.form-item.type-date input')`.

### Question

How do I access the attributes of the selector instance?

### P.S.

Tried to make a jsfiddle for this but couldn't get the jquery ui working with it for some reason. https://jsfiddle.net/zL8on6np/5/ Feel free to use this if you know how to get the libraries working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `$(this)` isn't what you expect is that it's not in a callback function of the selector, so it probably is in global scope.

You can iterate over the relevant `input` elements with jQuery's [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function like this:

```
$('.form-item.type-date input').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker(
    {
      'changeMonth' : $(this).attr('change_month') == "1",
      'changeYear' : $(this).attr('change_year') == "1",
      'yearRange' : $(this).attr('min_year') + ':' + $(this).attr('max_year')
    });
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/836/)**.

Comment: @danielson317 gotcha. I edited my answer to iterate over the input tags

Comment: Much better. This is exactly what I was looking for. Should have thought of this myself :). I'm more of a php guy though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no type `textfield` should be `text` :

```
<input type="text" name="dob" maxlength="10" size="12" value="07/01/2015" class="datepicker processed hasDatepicker" change_month="1" change_year="1" min_year="-120" max_year="+0" id="dp1452013829790">
```

hope this helps.

Comment: While in a strict sense you are correct every single browser (chrome, firefox, safari, opera, IE6+) supports `type="textfield"` and treats it as text input. So this is not really a solution. Perhaps move this feedback to a comment? Though support is probably just because type="text" is default and "textfield" is undefined.

Comment: Yes that true @daniel, you can use `type='anything'` and it will be text since text is the default type like you mentioned.